# What's the most efficient way to declare multiple values for a parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running a batch update script where @masterNameID in (21,22,23) but I'm getting syntax errors when I run this snippet;

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
DECLARE
@MasterNameID AS INT in (21,22,23)
,@RowCount AS INT
```

I've tried declaring a temp table by using the below but still can't get it to run;

```
Declare @MasterNameTlb table (MasterNameID INT (5))
 Insert into @MasterNameTlb (MasterNameID) values (21,22,23)
  Set @MasterNameID AS INT = select MasterNameID from @MasterNameTlb
```

Any ideas on how to get this to run or if there's a more efficient way to declare multiple values for an update script?

**Edit:

Apologies, What I'm trying to do here is amend an update script that will update in batches of 20k where values in (21,22,23). I'm getting syntax errors when trying "in (21,22,23)".  I also tried creating a temp table to pull the values from but still getting errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Full original script:

```
PRINT 'Shell_Index.SQL BEGIN'
If Object_ID('tempdb..#temp') Is Not Null
    DROP Table #temp
GO

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
DECLARE
@MasterNameID AS INT 
,@RowCount AS INT
DECLARE @Begin int
DECLARE @End int
DECLARE @Buffer int
DECLARE @MaxRec INT
SELECT
    et.ESTrackLogID
    ,et.ESFlagSync
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY et.ESTrackLogID) AS rn
    INTO #temp
FROM
      tbl1.ESTrackLog AS et
    JOIN tbl2  AS c ON c.ContactID = et.ESContactID
WHERE
   et.MasterNameID = @MasterNameID
    SELECT @RowCount = @@Rowcount
     print Cast(@RowCount as nvarchar) + ' row(s) inserted into #temp'
SELECT @Begin = min(rn) from #temp
SELECT @MaxRec = max(rn) from #temp
SELECT @Buffer = 20000
SELECT @End = @Buffer
WHILE @Begin <= @MaxRec
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN;
    UPDATE
        et
    SET
        et.ESFlagSync = 1
    FROM
        tbl1.ESTrackLog AS et
        JOIN #Temp                 AS a ON a.ESTrackLogID = et.ESTrackLogID
    WHERE
      et.MasterNameID = @MasterNameID
        AND a.rn BETWEEN @Begin and @End
    SELECT @RowCount = @@Rowcount
     print Cast(@RowCount as nvarchar) + ' row(s) updated in ESTrackLog'
    COMMIT TRAN
    if @RowCount > 0
    BEGIN
        WAITFOR delay '00:00:01';
    END
    SET @Begin = @End + 1
    SET @End = @End + @Buffer
END
PRINT 'Shell_Index.SQL DONE'
```

Comment: `@MasterNameID` is an `int` which is a **scalar** value, it *can't* hold multiple values. What are you actually trying to achieve here, as the above attempts are clearly part of an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: *"Declare @MasterNameTlb table (MasterNameID INT (5))"* This would generate a syntax error, `int` doesn't have a precision/scale parameter in SQL Server.

Comment: What are you planning to use the variable for?

Comment: `READ UNCOMMITTED` forget about this, forget you ever learned it existed. It's a bad idea, causes many concurrency issues, and is almost never necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to insert multiple values into a table variable. The correct syntax is:

```sql
Declare @MasterNameTlb table (MasterNameID INT);  -- use primary key?
Insert into @MasterNameTlb (MasterNameID) values (21),(22),(23);

select MasterNameID
from @MasterNameTlb AS t;
```

It's unclear exactly what you want to *do* with this table, but you can join it like any other.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [#MasterName];
GO
-- Example 1 into a TEMP table
Select [MasterName].[ID] INTO [#MasterName] FROM ( VALUES (21),(22),(23) )[MasterName]([ID]);
Select [TBL]= '[#MasterName]', * from [#MasterName];
-- Example 2 into a DECLARE table
Declare @MasterName TABLE ([ID] INT);
INSERT INTO @MasterName([ID])
Select [MasterName].[ID] FROM ( VALUES (21),(22),(23) )[MasterName]([ID]);
Select [TBL]= '@MasterName', * from @MasterName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to update some other table, not shown here, where a value is in (21,22,23)? Your temp table idea could work. After you create the temp table, you would do the update like this:

```
update mytable
set somecolumn = somevalue 
where somekey in (
    select * from @MasterNameTlb
);
```

If that's not what you trying to do, maybe add more detail to the question.

Comment: `IS IN` isn't valid syntax, it's just `IN`. Also, using `IN` against a `SELECT *` isn't a good idea.